# Is there a library similar to Math that supports JavaScript BigInt?

Tags: javascript, bigint

I am trying to use some functions of the Math library such as (pow, floor, etc). However, when I try to use them with a Big Int like this...

```
let x = Math.pow(100n, 100n);
```

I get

> TypeError: Cannot convert a BigInt value to a number

of course I can implement this myself, something like...

```
const BigMath ={
  pow(num, pow){
    let total;
    for(let i = 0; i < pow; i++){
      if(!total) total = num;
      else total = total * num;
    }
    return total;
  }
} 
let x = BigMath.pow(100n, 100n);
```

But I don't want to have to go back through and reimplement all of the functions. Especially since it seems like from my implementation it should be able to handle it no problem.

So how do I handle Math.* with a BigInt?

Answer (score 10):

For `pow()` you can simply use `**` operator:

```js
Math.pow(2, 175)
// 4.789048565205903e+52
2**175
// 4.789048565205903e+52
2n**175n
// 47890485652059026823698344598447161988085597568237568n
```

`floor()` like most `Math` functions is not relevant with integers.

In fact, only 5 `Math` functions seam to be relevant with integers:

- **`Math.abs()`**
- **`Math.max()`**
- **`Math.min()`**
- **`Math.pow()`**
- **`Math.sign()`**

All the other functions concern real numbers:

- Trigonometric functions (`cos`, `acos`, `sin`, `asin`, `tan`, `atan`, `atan2`)
- Hyperbolic functions (`cosh`, `acosh`, `sinh`, `asinh`, `tanh`, `atanh`)
- Roots (`sqrt`, `cbrt`, `hypot`)
- Round (`round`, `ceil`, `floor`, `trunc`)
- Logarithm (`exp`, `expm1`, `log`, `log10`, `log1p`, `log2`)
- Random (`random`)
- Bit (`clz32`, `fround`, `imul`)

So, here is the equivalent of `Math` for `BigInt`:

```js
const bigMath = {
  abs(x) {
    return x < 0n ? -x : x
  },
  sign(x) {
    if (x === 0n) return 0n
    return x < 0n ? -1n : 1n
  },
  pow(base, exponent) {
    return base ** exponent
  },
  min(value, ...values) {
    for (const v of values)
      if (v < value) value = v
    return value
  },
  max(value, ...values) {
    for (const v of values)
      if (v > value) value = v
    return value
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Basenumber.js](https://github.com/AlexSp3/Basenumber.js) which allows **BigInt** and **BigDecimal** operations:

#### Power

```js
let x = Base('100');
let y = Base('100');

let z = x.pow(y);

console.log( z.toString() );
console.log( z.toExponential(1) );
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/AlexSp3/Basenumber.js@main/BaseNumber.min.js'></script>
```

#### Division

```js
let x = Base('1e+10000');
let y = Base('999999999999999999999999999999999');

let z = x.divide(y);

console.log(z.toString());
console.log(z.toExponential(1));
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/AlexSp3/Basenumber.js@main/BaseNumber.min.js'></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

BigInts is a different datatype in its own way you can't have compare not use them as such in an expression

```
typeof 123;  // 'number'
typeof 123n; // 'bigint'
```

Numbers can't represent BigInts beyond the safe integer limit that's why it's not allowed to mix operations between BigInts and Numbers (except for comparison operators ===,<,>) as any implicit conversion could lose information

So what you can do is add an implicit casting

```
Number( Math.pow( Number(100n) , Number(100n) ) ); // 1.0000000000000005e+200
```

Comment: Wouldn't this round when it gets converted to number?

Comment: Yes it would, theres no inbuilt way to `pow` BigInts in javascript if that was your point then there already exists a [BigInt liberary](https://github.com/peterolson/BigInteger.js)  that would allow for it.

Comment: this will lose precision, use `**` operator instead